# Query for a Document Nested in an Array using Doctrine mongodb odm

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I want to execute [Document Nested in an Array queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) with the [Doctrine mongodb odm query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2.x/reference/query-builder-api.html)

I have basically a structure similar to :

> db.inventory.insertMany( [
>
> { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, {
>   warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
>
> { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
>
> { item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, {
>   warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
>
> ]);

I want to execute this shell query within the query builder

> db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } } )

I have tried this, but this won't work as it ignores the field 'instock'.

> $qb->field('instock')->field('warehouse')->equals('A')->field('qty')->equals(5)

Keep in mind that doing the following

> $qb->field('instock.warehouse')->equals('A')->field('instock.qty')->equals(5)

is a different logic ([check second example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#combination-of-elements-satisfies-the-criteria)), because it matches not necessarily the same embedded document.

I can implement it using $where and a loop, but it is ugly and slow. any better ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using $elemMatch, this is the way to solve this issue :

```
$qb->expr()->field('instock')->elemMatch(
        $qb->expr()
            ->field('warehouse')->equals('A')
            ->field('qty')->equals(5)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

ODM supports embedded documents via query builder so you can do the following:

```
$qb->field('instock')->equals(new InStock('A', 5));
```

If using objects is not what you want I think you can do away with associative array instead of `new InStock()`.

Comment: that way i would need the whole object data, i can't look for a specific field :(

Comment: @volkovmqx sorry then, was mislead by query using all fields that were in the data. Have you tried something like `$qb->field('instock')->equals(['warehouse' => 'A', 'qty' => 5]);`?

Comment: yes, it will match if a whole ['warehouse' => 'A', 'qty' => 5] exists, and in the same order, so ['warehouse' => 'A'] won't work

Comment: yes, that's how i solved this issue. i will share the answer